# jQuery - trigger('change') vs change()

Tags: jquery

**Edit: To clarify, what I want to ask is: In what scenario will you prefer one syntax over the another?**

What is the difference between:

`.trigger('change')` and `.change()`

Both works as expected. Is there any scenario where the syntax will make a difference?

Comment: `.change()` is short handler for `.trigger('change')`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its very well document https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: you can send variable using `.trigger('change')`

Comment: @guradio Does that mean `change()` cannot accompanied with parameters?

Answer (score 7):

The [JQuery documentation for .change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) says:

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "change", handler ) in the first
>   two variations, and .trigger( "change" ) in the third.

Answer (score 4):

Both trigger and change are events but trigger gives you a feature to call anywhere like here on page load.
If you want to call this change event on page load so u can use $(element).trigger('change').

```
$(element).on("change", function(){
    // statement
})

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(element).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: or when my listener is located in a different HTML layer, am I right?

Comment: Anywhere, but on the same page

Answer (score 0):

I recommand to use **`.trigger('change')`**, hence **`.change()`** is deprecated.